# bootstrap center links and text in panel-body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to center text in bootstrap, i dont know way the content in my footer is displayed crooked, this is the html code :

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <ul> © 2016 
          <a href="/">selfmarket.net</a> /
          <a href="/static/atom.xml">RSS Feed</a> /
          <a href="/static/sitemap.xml">sitemap.xml</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

live demo is : https://selfmarket.net/

the text need to be where is my red line :
[image]

Comment: Look into chrome's dev tools if you haven't already. It's super useful in adjusting code and testing different things. You can add css and manipulate the code without risk of losing your original codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an unordered list (`ul`) if you don't have any list elements.

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div> © 2016 
      <a href="/">selfmarket.net</a> /
      <a href="/static/atom.xml">RSS Feed</a> /
      <a href="/static/sitemap.xml">sitemap.xml</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your css page you need to align the items to the center:

```
.panel-body ul { text-align: center; }
```

However, I'm not sure why you are using an unordered list tag.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp Here is some documentation on unordered lists and proper uses.

Comment: @fl0cke I see -- the arrow threw me off

Comment: yeah me too. btw there is a `text-center` class in bootstrap ;)